# Make opencv java application work on cross-os (platform independent)

Tags: java, opencv, compilation, cross-platform

I have an application written with cv using opencv. It was coded on macos x. But I want that it works on linux and windows. I know how to do that, put "dll","so", "dblib" files into project folder and assign library path to this path. But my question is where can I find this "dll" and "so" files. I compiled it on macos x environment therefore I don't have such files.
Please help.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I have the same problem.

Comment: unfortunately no. I am sorry, I can't help

Answer (score 0):

First, download OpenCV from [OpenCV.org](http://opencv.org/downloads.html)

extract file in a directory `C:\` you get all library  in `C:\opencv\sources\3rdparty` directory.